# kivy .kv file won't read

Tags: python, kivy

I have just started learning to program. I have a really basic App based on a pong game tutorial on the kivy.org website, but I must have a basic flaw that I can't see, because when I run the program, all I am getting is a blank screen rather than the expected canvas and labels.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Singularity(Widget):
    pass

class SingularityApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Singularity()

if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    SingularityApp().run()
```

and the singularity.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<Singularity>:    
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height
            
    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
        
    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

Comment: I'm unsure whether this is your problem (not likely), but I've had an issue with floor division in Kivy in the past. If you're running this under python 2, you need to account for floor division even in your *.kv file. This means `center_x: root.width * 3 / 4` should be `center_x: root.width * 3.0 / 4.0`.

Comment: The name of the file "name.kv" should be in lowercase name.kv

Answer (score 11):

- Check whether your `MainApp(App)` class name is same as your **.kv** file name without the 'App' (if not, make them the same). It's not case sensitive. For example: `MaNagerApp(App)` will load **manager.kv**.

**OR**

- If you don't want to change name then simply add `self.load_kv(your_kv_file_name)`, like this:

  ```py
  def build(self):
      self.load_kv('singularity.kv')
      return Singularity()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Make your .kv file name as same as main Class name
ex:

```
class galaxyApp(App): # this is your main class
    pass
galaxyApp().run()
```

make your .kv file name same as main class name (not case sensitive). In my case my .kv file name will be "galaxy.kv"

Comment: This was already mentioned in the (highly upvoted) answer. Could you clarify what the added value of this answer is?