# How to display game on the screen?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an kivy app with starting menu, but I can't display my Pong Game on the second screen. How should I refer to the game to make it visible? I tried and searched but can't find anything. I'm 100% sure that PongGame work corectly, I just can't display it. It would be great if someone could show me how to do it corectly.

Main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
    ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))

        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))
            if self.player1.score == 10:
                popup = Popup(title='Test popup', content=Label(text='Hello world'), auto_dismiss=False)
                return popup
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_three = ObjectProperty(None)

class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=WipeTransition())
        return m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

screen.kv:

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y

<ScreenOne>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 1 >> Screen 2"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'
<ScreenTwo>:
        def build(self):
            game = PongGame()
            game.serve_ball()
            Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
            return game

<ScreenThree>:
    Button:
        text: "Screen 3 >> Screen 1"
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two
    screen_three: screen_three

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: 'screen1'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: 'screen2'
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenThree:
        id: screen_three
        name: 'screen3'
        manager: screen_manager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! there were a lot of errors in your program and I had to make ton's of improvement. (I understand it as you are beginner)

First of all, please read complete [kivy language documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html), as I can clearly see that you directly started with coding without grasping the basics.
You may make couple of good games but in the long run you will face such problems which can't be solved without clear concepts. 
And unfortunately you won't be able to discover the true power of **kivy**. :)

You might also wanna do revision of your python concepts.

Some improvements aren't worth mentioning but were important, you will get an idea when you read the code.

**Improvement 1:**

An application can be built if you return a widget on build(), or if you set self.root.(But you cannot make the application again n again)
 as you did here:

```
<ScreenTwo>:
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game
```

**Improvement 2:**

As you click on button **play ping pong** which is of screen game. your game starts with serve of ball.

```
on_release: root.current = 'game';game.serve_ball()
```

**(for knowledge)**

If you still get black screen you might want to check the name of kivy file, for that you could either go to kivy documentation or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430780/python-kivy-kv-file-wont-read/30534840#30534840)

```
 class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

    #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
        self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

    #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('t6.kv')
        return Manager(transition=WipeTransition())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Here is the kv file.

```
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y

    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y

<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager


    Screen:
        name: 'home'
        Button:
            text: 'Play Ping Pong'
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            font_size: 100
            text_size: self.size
            on_release: root.current = 'game';game.serve_ball()

    Screen:
        name: 'game'
        PongGame:
            id: game
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I'm more than beginner and your advices are very helpful. Now everything works fine and it's easy to understand why. Once again thank you very much! :)