# Kivy - unable to run the game on widget that is added to second screen

Tags: python, kivy

I have posted two posts about the same problem a few days ago, but I still can't get it to run.

I have two screens. Two buttons on first screen (Play and How to play). The second one does what I want, but I would like the first one to begin the game when released, as well as change Screen to second Screen (this works okay).
I have tried a lot of things and I always get errors about SnakeWidget not being defined, not containing self and so on.

That's the error I get:

```
 File "C:\Users\Lara\Desktop\KIVY\LARA\poskus.py", line 33, in <module>
     class GameScreen(Screen):
 File "C:\Users\Lara\Desktop\KIVY\LARA\poskus.py", line 34, in GameScreen
     snaky_game = SnakeWidget()
NameError: name 'SnakeWidget' is not defined
```

.py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder


class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass

class StartScreen(Screen):
    def show_popup(self):
        p = InstructionsPopup(content=Label(text="Instructions"))
        p.open()

class GameScreen(Screen):
    snaky_game = SnakeWidget()
    snaky_game.begin()
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

class InstructionsPopup(Popup):
    pass

class SnakeWidget(Widget):
    snaky = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SnakeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def begin(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.snaky.center = self.center
        self.snaky.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.snaky.move()

        if (self.snaky.y < self.y) or (self.snaky.top > self.top):
            self.snaky.velocity_y *= -1

class Snake(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

class PoskusApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv("poskus.kv")
        return RootScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PoskusApp().run()
```

and .kv file:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<RootScreen>:
    id: screen_manager
    transition: FadeTransition()
    StartScreen:
        name: "start"
    GameScreen:
        name: "game"

<StartScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        name: "start"
        Button: 
            id: play
            text: "Play!"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.3
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            font_size: 70
            on_release: root.manager.current = "game"
        Button: 
            id: how
            text: "How to play"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3}
            font_size: 40
            on_press: root.show_popup()
<InstructionsPopup>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    title: "How to play"

<GameScreen>:
    name: "game"
    SnakeWidget:
    Button:
        id: menu
        text: "Menu"
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.8,"y":0.9}
        font_size: 17
        on_release: root.manager.current  = "start"

<SnakeWidget>:
    id: snake_widget
    snaky: snake
    canvas: 
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Snake: 
        id: snake
        center: self.parent.center  

<Snake>:
    size: 50, 50 
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: 40, 40
```

If you can, please help me because I am stuck and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed a couple of python basics. I will explain in form of points.

**1**. You forgot to import properties that you used in your python code.

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty,ReferenceListProperty,ObjectProperty
```

**2**. You need to know how the python interpreter works, **It reads your code from top to bottom**, Here class `GameScreen` is defined before defining `SnakeWidget` class, So when you try to make an object of `SnakeWidget` class which doesn't exists for the interpreter. It shows an error. `NameError: name 'SnakeWidget' is not defined`. So basically, move your class `GameScreen` below the class `SnakeWidget` and that shall fix the error.

**3**. You used `self` when you tried to schedule your function. `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)`

Using `self` would say that there is a method named `update` in the same class itself instead of looking in the `SnakeWidget` class.

```
class GameScreen(Screen):
    snaky_game = SnakeWidget()
    snaky_game.begin()
    Clock.schedule_interval(snaky_game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
```

Comment: I do have those imports in my actual file but yesterday you removed all the imports that i didn't need in my code and now I removed some that I do need by mistake, sorry about that. Thanks for the class order, I completely forgot that this matters! Unfortunetly it still gives me an error but a different one. It says that NoneType object has no attribute center.

Comment: I know about that error, but sorry to say, I cannot make the whole code for you, when you asked a similar question some days ago, I gave you a link. I think it's time that you go through it and grasp every concept and trick that you see in that answer and **trust me**, it will clear all your doubts. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943024/how-to-display-game-on-the-screen/30944888#30944888

Comment: I know, sorry. I did go through it twice and changed a lot of things, but abandoned it because it would not work. I will try again, sorry about asking so much and thank you for answering all my posts!

Comment: I am happy to help. :) After you are tired of trying and still got doubts or got stuck then don't hesitate to ask another question, after all that's what this site is for, right? :D Your questions might help someone in the future. Ah. And also, after you solve the problem mark these answers as accepted. :)

Comment: @Uros1234, you should mark answers as accepted if you want people to keep answering your questions

Comment: finally got it to work :) The problem was that I had two classes and defined their id in ScreenManager rule, so when I tried to call game.begin() before that rule, it would say game is not defined because I defined it later. Thanks for the help!