# Pass variable value from main.py to .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get value of a variable named `h` from main.py file to my `.kv` file, but all I get is a blank screen.

This is my `main.py`

```
class ExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        h="SoME STRING IS HERE "
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

This is my `.kv` file

```
Label:
    text:root.h.text
```

Comment: See here  if you got anything wrong related to connection with kivy file . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430780/python-kivy-kv-file-wont-read/30534840#30534840

Comment: I tried both...but didnt work...

Comment: What do you return in build method?

Comment: As you can see in script i haven't given anything without pass in build ... In output i just want a label that have text stored in h variable which is my main.py file

Answer (score 3):

That's how you do it.

python file

```
class ExampleApp(App):
    h="SoME STRING IS HERE "
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('t3.kv')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

kivy file

```
Label:
    text: app.h #Here's the main difference
```

Comment: But what if h variable is in some function

Comment: If you want to change that value of the string in some function, than I suggest you to use `StringProperty`  Do it this way `from kivy.properties import StringProperty`  and then `h = StringProperty("SoME STRING IS HERE ")`

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: What if there is another function like def my_s(): in my class and there is variable named h there and h ='somestring' so how can i take the string stored in the h i tried to put app.h in my kv file but it didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83146/discussion-between-kiok46-and-nisarg).